# Подключить третью таблицу

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * FROM users A INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM [BASE].[dbo].[list]) AS B ON A.idname = B.user_id
```

Выводит замечательно 2 таблицы.

Цель: в таблице 1 лежат данные пользователей (ФИО, год рождения. и др.), а в таблице list лежат только идентификаторы этих пользователей, не могу подключить третью таблицу, чтобы список был из таблицы list и list1, но данные были из users.

Данные в таблице user:
idname surname name patronymic age
pupkin65 Пупкин Иван Иваныч 1965
vasukov63 Васюков Петр Генадьевич 1963
permskii63 Пермский Денис Грегорьевич 1961
moskva64 Москва Сергей Иванович 1964

list1
user_id
moskva64
vasukov63

list
user_id
pupkin65
permskii63
vasukov63

нужно вывести данные как в таблице users но только тех кто в таблице list и list1

Comment: пока нет ответа верного.

Comment: @big-vl, приведите пример данных и ожидаемый результат. "выбирает данные вбок" наводит на мысль, что правильного и не будет при такой постановке вопроса.

Comment: поправил вопрос...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вложенный запрос не нужен:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*
FROM users A 
  INNER JOIN list B ON A.idname = B.user_id
```

И далее просто добавляете еще одну связь аналогичным join'ом.

**UPD** Выбирайте:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM users A 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT user_id FROM list UNION SELECT user_id FROM list1) B ON A.idname = B.user_id
```

или

```
SELECT A.*
FROM users A
WHERE idname in (SELECT user_id FROM list UNION SELECT user_id from list1)
```

или

```
SELECT A.*
FROM users A
WHERE idname in (SELECT user_id FROM list) or idname in (SELECT user_id from list1)
```

или

```
SELECT A.*
FROM users A
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM list WHERE user_id=A.idname) 
  or EXISTS (SELECT 1 from list1 WHERE user_id=A.idname)
```

результат будет один и тот же (впрочем можно подобрать данные, что результат будет отличаться).

Comment: выводит user_id и user_id_1 сбоку, а нужен лист из user_id

Comment: @big-vl, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

1. Выводите только нужные поля, а не все полностью (*)
2. Для выбора из 3 таблицы "вызовите" JOIN еще раз.

Answer (score 0):

Если данные нужны только из таблицы users, то остается только сделать 2-й join и указать, что данные брать только из таблицы с алиасом А. Вот как будет выглядеть запрос:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM users as A
INNER JOIN [BASE].[dbo].[list] AS B 
ON (A.idname = B.user_id)
INNER JOIN [BASE].[dbo].[list1] AS B1 
ON (A.idname = B1.user_id)
```

Comment: В базе list - 124 записей, а в базе 202, а он выводит какие-то 19 записей (! цифры по выводу придуманы), в целом он не выводит список из списка.

Comment: Мы тут пальцем в небо тыкаем, пытаясь понять, что у вас там за таблицы и какие между ними связи. Я ещё раз перечитал вопрос и хочу понять, что есть "чтобы список был из таблицы list и list1" ? У вас какая исходная таблица?

Comment: users там хранятся данные, он выбирает данные вбок, мне как то надо что бы все записи из таблицы list и list1 выбрались все вместе в одном столбце обьедененном user_id а то он и user_id_1 выбирает у меня нет такого столбца в таблице

Comment: Если у вас одинаковые названия столбцов в нескольких таблицах, то он будет добавлять постфикс _1,_2,_3 к каждому следующему одинаковому столбцу.
Я предлагаю вам обновить вопрос и показать пример данных во всех таблицах и как вы хотите их вывести. А то в вопросе вы говорите, что вам нужно данные из users, а в предыдущем комментарии, что данные из list и list1 нужны.

Comment: поправил вопрос